# insert logic with while python

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a bunch of list that contains some name who have access, if the name is true and on the list, then it will print welcome to that name, otherwise, if the user had more than 3 wrongs, then it will print sorry, you're more than 3 times wrong. for that logic, I use this

```
secret_word = ['Fachry', 'Amri', 'Hasbi']
word = ''
guess = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while word != secret_word and not(out_of_guesses):
    if guess < guess_limit:
        word = input('What is your real name? ')
        guess += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True
if out_of_guesses:
    print("Sorry, you're more than 3 times wrong")
else:
    print('Welcome mr ' + secret_word)
```

but when I input the name, no matter is true or not, it will repeat 3 times and will return "Sorry, you're more than 3 times wrong" even though the name is on the list

**Expected results:**

if I put one of the names inside the list, it will return welcome (the name itself), as long as the users didn't do 3 more times wrong names

Comment: instead of `word != secret_word`, use `not in`; you can can't compare string with list!

Comment: Yes: while word not in secret_word and not(out_of_guesses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `while-else` and avoid initializing `word` and `out_of_guesses` outside `while` loop using below code

```
secret_word = ['Fachry', 'Amri', 'Hasbi']
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3

while guess_count < guess_limit:
    word = input('What is your real name? ')

    if word in secret_word:
        print('Welcome mr ' + word)
        break

    guess_count += 1

else:
    print("Sorry, you're more than 3 times wrong")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to check word is in `search_word` or not. So, your condition should be like `word not in secret_word`. Whereas you're printing `print('Welcome mr ', word)` that's print the whole list. You can print instead the input word to verify.

```
secret_word = ['Fachry', 'Amri', 'Hasbi']
word = ''
guess = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while word not in secret_word and not(out_of_guesses):
    if guess < guess_limit:
        word = input('What is your real name? ')
        guess += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True
if out_of_guesses:
    print("Sorry, you're more than 3 times wrong")
else:
    print('Welcome mr ', word)
```

If you need to clean code then you can follow this

```
secret_word = ['Fachry', 'Amri', 'Hasbi']
word = ''
guess = 0
guess_limit = 3

while guess < guess_limit:
    word = input('What is your real name? ')
    if word in secret_word:
        print('Welcome mr ', word)
        break
    guess += 1
    if guess >= guess_limit:
        print("Sorry, you're more than 3 times wrong")
```